# SwiftUI: List in a Tabview always reset after tab change

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios13

In my app I have a TabView with lists in there.
When I scroll a list and than change tabs forth and back, the list is always reset and starts from the top...

But this shouldn't be the case...
Is this a bug, or what I'm doing wrong?

Here is some example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       TabView {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) {
                        Text("Row in Tab 1 Number: \($0)")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Tab 1")
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bubble.right")
                Text("Tab 1")
            }.tag(0)

            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) {
                        Text("Row in Tab 2 Number: \($0)")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Tab 2")
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bubble.left")
                Text("Tab 2")
            }.tag(1)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a (easy) solution/workaround for this? Or swiftui is simply not production-ready yet and full of bugs?

Comment: See here: https://gist.github.com/Amzd/2eb5b941865e8c5cccf149e6e07c8810

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that every view is a value, and on every update it is performed complete recreation of view hierarchy, and List for now does not have anything similar to visibleRange property or modifier... I would say it is a feature.

Comment: It not only resets the List, it also reset a Navigation Stack... I don't think, this is a feature...

Answer (score 1):

OK..

This seems to be a known bug as mentioned here:
[SwiftUI Bugs on github](https://github.com/ryangittings/swiftui-bugs)

There you can find a workaround for this...